# Scipy Portfolio Optimisation with high level constraints

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, scipy, finance

new to the forum so hopefully this question is explained correctly.

I am trying to create an optimized portfolio using Scipy by importing an excel table (example below). The objective is to minimize the negative ratio of expected return to risk factor (i.e. -Expected return/Risk factor).

```
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+
| Asset_Class | Asset_Class2 | Expected Return | Risk Factor |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+
| Govt        | Sov          | 0.6%            | 0.5%        |
| Govt        | Muni         | 1.3%            | 0.5%        |
| Govt        | Supra        | 1.5%            | 0.5%        |
| Corp        | HY           | 10.0%           | 20.0%       |
| Corp        | Financials   | 1.6%            | 5.0%        |
| Corp        | Industrials  | 1.3%            | 5.0%        |
| Corp        | Utilites     | 1.8%            | 5.0%        |
| Corp        | EM           | 6.0%            | 10.0%       |
| Equity      | Growth       | 8.0%            | 30.0%       |
| Equity      | Value        | 6.0%            | 20.0%       |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

The problem I am having is that I need to apply constraints to the portfolio at the 'Asset_Class' level so, for example, the sum of the weights applied to the Sov, Muni & Supra bucket must be >10% and <100%. An example of the limits table is below.

```
+-------------+-----------+------------+
| Asset_Class | Low_Limit | High_Limit |
+-------------+-----------+------------+
| Govt        | 10%       | 100%       |
| Corp        | 10%       | 60%        |
| Equity      | 0%        | 10%        |
+-------------+-----------+------------+
```

Any ideas how the weights can be constrained at the grouped level?
Thanks for your help!

Edit: expected output would be a dataframe grouped by 'Asset_Class2' (or 'Asset_Class'), example below, with expected return and risk also being output.

```
+--------------+--------+
| Asset_Class2 | Weight |
+--------------+--------+
| Sov          | 0.2    |
| Supra        | 0.1    |
| HY           | 0.15   |
| Financials   | 0.2    |
| Industrials  | 0.015  |
| Utilities    | 0.1    |
| EM           | 0.185  |
| Growth       | 0.02   |
| Value        | 0.03   |
+--------------+--------+

+--------------------------+-------+
| Weighted Expected Return | 0.041 |
| Weighted Risk Factor     | 0.112 |
+--------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Do you mind to show your expected output?

Comment: Hi rpanai, the output would be a dataframe grouped by 'Asset_Class2' (or 'Asset_Class'), example below.

+--------------------------+------------+
|                          | Allocation |
+--------------------------+------------+
| Govt                     |       0.45 |
| Corp                     |       0.50 |
| Eq                       |       0.05 |
| Weighted Expected Return |      0.041 |
| Weighted Risk Factor     |      0.112 |
+--------------------------+------------+

I've appended the expected return and risk to the end.
Let me know if I can provide any other info.

Comment: please update your question.